# Ubuntu Server 20.04 can't Find/Connect to Hidden Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

**[ 1. Summarize the problem ]**

Unable to access a Hidden Wifi Access Point via the use of Network Manager and/or Netplan

**[ 2. Provide details and any research ]**

Using a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Other than the addition of a RTC Hat, no modifications to the hardware.

Attempting to use Network Manager with the intent of switching/connecting to multiple Access Points, Hidden or otherwise.

**[ 3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried ]**

*For a summary (and not listing my past two days of efforts):*

[Reference](https://blog.khmersite.net/2019/01/how-to-connect-to-hidden-wifi-using-nmcli/)

*Added the connection info*

```
sudo nmcli con add type wifi con-name Hidden_Test ifname wlp590 ssid <SSID>
Connection 'Hidden_Test' (e64a9fff-f74f-451b-9876-84a9085f9902) successfully added.

sudo nmcli con mod Hidden_Test wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
sudo nmcli con mod Hidden_Test wifi-sec.psk <PASSWORD>
sudo nmcli con mod Hidden_Test 802-11-wireless.hidden yes
sudo nmcli con up Hidden_Test 
Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=e64a9fff-f74f-451b-9876-84a9085f9902 + NM_DEVICE=wlan0' to get more details.
```

*Checked the journalctl logs*

```
sudo journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=e64a9fff-f74f-451b-9876-84a9085f9902 + NM_DEVICE=wlan0

(wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Hidden_Test' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
(wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
(wlan0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
(wlan0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'Hidden_Test'
(wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
(wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 62:49:B2:DB:41:16 (scanning)
(wlan0): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you trackable
(wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'Hidden_Test' (e64a9fff-f74f-451b-9876-84a9085f9902)
(wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to E4:5F:01:49:58:13 (preserve)
(wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Hidden_Test' has security, but secrets are required.
(wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
(wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> disabled
(wlan0): supplicant interface state: disabled -> disconnected
```

Kind of looks like it is finding the Access Point, but then not? And it's changing the state from disconnected to disabled and back again?

*Anyway...to check something.*

```
sudo nmcli con show Hidden_Test
...
...
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 yes
...
```

*Checking in on the NetworkManager.conf*

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes
```

There have been many other attempts following various other links (I could link the 15+ sites I went through) including not adding the hidden value, a few with different nmcli options/settings, many suggesting wpa_supplicant, some with wpa_supplicant.dhcp, various others saying that it's better to use Netplan, which I did attempt that route, but prefer to stay with Network-Manager is possible.

*If you are curious about the .yaml file*

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

network:
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
      wlan0:
        #hidden: true # only in netplan 0.100
        dhcp4: true
        access-points:
          "SSID":
             hidden: true
             password: "PASSWORD"
```

I've noticed that the use of Netplan AND Network-Manager will produce odd conflicts, sometimes creating duplicate wpa_supplicant processes (I read about them as well). I also followed some steps in attempt to ensure that Netplan will use Network-Manager (as can be seen in the file pasted). This method, after 'sudo netplan generate' & 'sudo netplan apply,' will generate it's own device/connection name, and when 'sudo nmcli c up' that connection, it will produce the same issues as stated earlier.

I'm at a loss here, and most of the "solutions" I have discovered in the many articles out there either work for the author, or aren't confirmed, and either way, they don't work for me, so I assume I am missing something.

Anyone out there able to help with this?